How do I get the cookies without having to pass them to API functions from server components?
I can get the cookies in server side components and pass them to API functions like this:
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

const cookieStore = cookies();
const sessionId = cookieStore.get('SESSIONID.DEV')?.value;

const asset = await queryClient.fetchQuery({
  queryKey: ['asset', params.id],
  queryFn: () => fetchData(params.id, sessionId),
});

console.log('Fetched asset:', asset);

Then in api.ts, I have something like this (otherwise, the cookies won't be sent in server side components, and I'll get a 401 unauthorized error):
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: getBaseUrl(),
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/hal+json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});
 
export const fetchData = async (id: string, sessionId: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(`/data/${id}`, {
      headers: {
        'Accept-Version': '0.24.0.0',
        Cookie: `SESSIONID.DEV=${sessionId}`,
      },
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching current asset', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

But I don't want to pass sessionId to every API function, so I tried getting the cookies in my api.ts file. However, I got this error:

Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.

So it seems like I can only use Next.js' cookies in server components. How can I solve this dilemma?

How are these files structured? You mentioned the first one is a server component where you can retrieve the cookies and pass it to the other file, but where is the api.ts and what is it? Isn’t it a server component then?

api.ts is just a regular file. It's not a React server component.

What is the problem with passing the cookies to that api thing? Why can’t it be a server action itself? Please provide a codesandbox with the code so we can get better overview of what you are trying to do

If you have any concerns or questions about the issue raised, please share them in the comment section. Use the answer section only for solution responses.
